# Unable to listen to $ionicView.loaded?

Tags: javascript, mobile, ionic-framework

I am trying to perform some actions when the view first loads. According to the ion-view documentation (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/), I should listen to the event `$ionicView.loaded`, which fires when the view is first loaded (*The view has loaded. This event only happens once per view being created and added to the DOM*).

I am trying to listen the following way:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.loaded", function(event, data){
      // handle event
      console.log("IONIC VIEW LOADED");
      //updateScansList(db, $scope); //Populate list from table
 });
```

When executing the program, I expect to see "IONIC VIEW LOADED" on the console, but that never happens.

Is there a mistake that I am not catching? Is there a better way to listen to the first load of a View in Ionic?

Thank you!

Comment: You should have `<ion-view>` in your html page. (the page controlled by this controller of course). if you don't have `<ion-view>` any `$ionicView` event doesn't fire.

Comment: The page does have `<ion-view>`, and I know that $ionicView works because `$ionicView.enter` does trigger every time the view goes into focus, except when the app opens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$ionicView.enter` is a better place to first load setup.

Comment: I am also listening to that event. It was my first option, but that event doesn't fire when the view is initially loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using the tabs starter application and placed your $ionicView.loaded code in the ChatsCtrl.

The application loaded fine on the first view but the "IONIC VIEW LOADED" message did not appear until I went to the Chats View.

You are correct in your thinking, because "loaded" will only happen once when the view first loads, whereas "enter" should happen every time you enter the view.